# I have an old media wiki root dir, I am not certain if I'm able to restore it

Tags: mediawiki

This is an older installation for which I have (what I believe to be) the full root directory of the mediawiki site.
The version of mediawiki is `1.26`.

I know the permissions on the directory are not correct and have been messed around with (`touch`) files by other users, etc.

As I'm not very familiar with mediawiki, I understand the database or a dump of it are very important.
I cannot determine which db was used for this installation, as `grep -RiI wgDBname` only produces mentions of the `wgDBname` , but not an actual DBname being used.

I followed all applicable steps in https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Restoring_a_wiki_from_backup#External_links , however this link assumes some knowledge of the DB location (or even which DB was used in the first place).

I've issued
`find . -name *.sql -exec ls -lh {} \; > /tmp/output` and so on, to try and find `(files > just a few KB)` in size, to perhaps find a DB that way (assuming it was a mysql DB), and it may have been a postgres installation, and so on.
Any pointers to a possible search direction would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The configuration is stored in `LocalSettings.php`.
Do you really need to restore the old MediaWiki installation? If you have your images directory, and, at least, a mySQL server (in which you can search for your MediaWiki database), why not install MediaWiki anew, with needed extensions and run the `update.php`? Back up the datavase before that.

Comment: thank you, @AlexanderMashin, my `LocalSettings.php` is an empty file, it does lead me to believe something was not done right when the root dir was backed up. 

IRRC, I was told the backup was obtained via `sftp` or `scp -r` which explains the bad permissions. 

`du -ch images` produces `151M    total` which could be promising. 
If I can't obtain any copy of the previous DB, would the `images` directory do just by itself ?

Comment: I don't think that the images without the articles (which are in the database) will be any good.

Comment: That's too bad then :( is there a way for me to determine whether this root directory has the database ? (I can't think why it would not, it's seemingly just a full dump of the directory).  I just can't seem to find it :(

Comment: I don't think that a directory can have a database (unless it was SQLite, which is a rare choice for MediaWiki). If you mean that there could either be `$wgDBname` value or mySQL dumps, you have already grepped for them. I think you should try searching for the database by examining all mySQL/PostgreSQL servers in your network: first working, then stopped. What you should realise is that the database is usually unrelated to MediaWiki installation directory/web root.

Comment: Alas, the root dir (and the DB) were hosted on a server that's not under my control (by a web hosting company such NameCheap), the server is probably long gone by now. It seems like I'm out of luck (unless sqlite was indeed the choice). I will do some more searching but I thank you @AlexanderMashin for shedding some significant light on the paths to solution.